# How to keep id on mongoose findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a 'Board' model in mongoose using findByIdAndUpdate and the model has an array of 'items' (which are objects) on the model. I probably do not understand mongoose well enough but for some reason each item in the array gets an id generated, along with the Board. This is not a problem, it's quite handy actually, however, after doing a findByIdAndUpdate the id on each item has changed. This was quite surprising to me, I really thought they would stay the same. Could this be caused by updating all items in the array? Maybe mongoose is just throwing out the entire array and creating a new one when updating (maybe someone knows?). Anyways, my question is: Is there a way to update the model without changing these id's. I would really like them to stay consistent. The code I am using for update is

```js
exports.updateBoard = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  let board = await Board.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!board) {
    return next(new CustomError(`Board not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404));
  }

  // Authorize user
  if (board.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
    return next(new CustomError(`User ${req.user.id} is not authorized to update board ${board._id}`, 401));
  }

  req.body.lastUpdated = Date.now();

  board = await Board.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true })
                              .select('-__v')
                              .populate({
                                path: 'user',
                                select: 'name avatar',
                              });

  // 200 - success
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: board });

});
```

and BoardSchema:

```js
const BoardSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Board must have a user'],
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      trim: true,
    },
    items: [
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true,
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
          trim: true,
        },
        dateCreated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
        lastUpdated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
      },
    ],
    columns: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        index: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        show: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    dateCreated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    lastUpdated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);
```

Comment: "Maybe mongoose is just throwing out the entire array and creating a new one when updating (maybe someone knows?)." - This is true. You are setting the document equal to req.body. You aren't editing the existing document as much as replacing it.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Would it be better to pull the specific properties off req.body I want and pass that instead?

Comment: I don't have a super clean way to solve this (one reason I didn't make it an answer), but yes, pulling off specific properties and updating them would keep anything you didn't update the same. If you update the items with the same _id t should remain intact through the update statement.

Comment: I'll try it out and see at least. Appreciate you taking the time to look at it!